# Problems finding some Sovjet references

Tags: optics, photoelectric-effect, specific-reference

I'm trying to find any of these references below.

1. I. D. Yaroshetskii and S. M. Ryvkin, in Problems of Modern Physics (in Russian), ed. V. M. Tuchkevich and V. Ya. Frenkel (Nauka, Leningrad, 1980), pp. 173-185 [English translation: Semiconductor Physics, ed. V.M. Tuchkevich and V.Ya. Frenkel (Cons. Bureau, New York, 1986) pp.
   249-263].
2. L. E. Gurevich and A. A. Rumyantsev, Fiz. Tverd. Tela 9, 75 (1967) [Sov. Phys. Solid State 9, 55 (1967)].
3. V. I. Perel and Ya. M. Pinskii, Fiz. Tverd. Tela 15, 996 (1973) [Sov. Phys. Solid State 15, 688 (1973)].
4. L. E. Gurevich and V. S. Travnikov, in Problems of Modern Physics (in Russian), ed. V. M. Tuchkevich and V. Ya. Frenkel (Nauka, Leningrad, 1980), pp. 262-268 [English translation: Semiconductor Physics, ed. V. M. Tuchkevich and V. Ya. Frenkel (Cons. Bureau, New York, 1986) pp. 331-344].

Comment: I'd be happy if you could provide any legal website in which I could download that, @Frobenius. What I meant is that is impossible to find it anywere.

Comment: interlibrary loan service of your university?

Comment: Some of these *may* be available via [Stanford Libraries Searchworks](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/488777).  I do not myself have access to that but if you can find a way via inter library loans you might find something.

Comment: 1 and 4 are from a book, likely you get on inter-library loan. 2 and 3 are journal articles, with both the Russian journal and the English translation cited. Interestingly, the Soviet Physics Solid State (translation and publishing through the American Institute of Physics) seems to have disappeared off the face of the earth (and AIP's website), don't know why.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about finding references and not about physics or another stack Exchange topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a partial answer, the journal *Sov. Phys. Solid State* has several entries in WorldCat, including e.g. [this one](https://www.worldcat.org/title/soviet-physics-solid-state/oclc/1642598). The same seems to be true of [*Semiconductor Physics*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/semiconductor-physics/oclc/260093259&referer=brief_results). If you enter your location, WorldCat will provide you with a list of the geographically-closest libraries that have the journal. If you can go to those libraries, it's often the simplest approach.

However, more generally, the simplest approach is very often to ask your librarian for help, and they will have a suitable Inter-Library Loan channel through which they can get an (often electronic) copy. If you are at a university, you likely have a paid professional whose job it is to help you get the literature you need.